# print values from multidimensional associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have multidimensional array which contain values from database table but values are key value format so I tried to print using foreach loop but unable to get output ,so  how to do this using foreach loop
after `print_r()` getting output like this.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($product_info);


Array
(
    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [data1] => "value1"  
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [data2] => "value2"  
                )
        )
    [type] => 6
)

foreach ($product_info as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
         foreach ($val as $c => $d) {
            echo "" . $c . " is " . $d . ".";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
foreach ($product_info as $key => $val) {

    //look for specific key. And do action if needed.
    if($key=='product'){

        $all = 0;
        $all = COUNT($val); //Count lines

        //loop lines
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $all; $x++) {

            //check if line exist
            if(isset($val[$x])){

                //loop through lines and echo data
                foreach ($val[$x] as $c => $d) {

                    echo $c.' '.$d.'<br>';

                }
            }
        }       


    }

    if($key=='type'){       
        echo 'This is type: '.$val;
    }   

}
```

You should edit it for your needs but this is how you could do it!

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @Ingus but using multiple foreach loop will affect performance

Comment: @user_1234 Maybe i m wrong but i do not think so. .. Also if so show me code that will not!

Comment: @user_1234 also i do not think you can access values without looping them.

Comment: None of us here is making money, we're all volunteers who try to help. I am just telling you that you can improve the quality of your answer by . explaining what you did.

Comment: @JayBlanchard What to do if i do not know how to explain?:D

Comment: How can you write code without knowing how to explain it? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JayBlanchard Its a gift :D I know what i need to make and i reached my goal. .. But I m bad on explaining!

Comment: @user_1234 Have you tested it?

Comment: @ Ingus yes , it is working thanks for your  support

Answer (score 0):

You can try to:

```
array_shift($product_info)
```

And then use foreach() on it or simply iterate over:

```
$product_info['product']
```

Comment: Looking at his foreach(){...} code, I assume he needs to get into next level of array which has only 'product' (there is nothing in the code for retrieving 'type' part) , that is why array_shift() would still be a safe solution.

Comment: In case OP only needs `product` this is fine